# unable to add entry into MySQL from iOS

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, post

**UPDATE**

Despite the different posts around here, I have not found a solution to add an entry in my MySQL table. I post a json dictionary from an iOS app and I would like to enter it in the database. It consists of an entry with 4 fields (firstname, lastname...). Below is the php code on the server side (running locally with MAMP):

```
<?php

DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'syncList');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno(). ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonArray = json_decode($body);

echo json_encode($jsonArray); // ---> send back for testing.

$firstname = $jsonArray['firstname']; 
$firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($firstname);

$lastname = $jsonArray['lastname'];
$lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($lastname);

$eds = $jsonArray['eds'];

$dateOfBirth = $jsonArray['dateOfBirth'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_syncList (firstname, lastname, EDS, dateOfBirth) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$eds', '$dateOfBirth')";


if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

The problem seems to be that my json_array[key] (like '$firstname') is not recognized since when I write my json_array to file, I see that the key is inside square brackets, like if it was an array with one element:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [firstname] => Robert
    [eds] => 1234567
    [lastname] => Redford
    [dateOfBirth] => 12.01.1965
)
```

***Is this a normal finding or could it explain why I cannot extract the value in my sql statement?*** And I cannot return an array object instead of a stdClass Object, even if I use json_decode($body, TRUE).

I add the obj-C code sending my dictionary with POST method. This is calling the php script above.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setValue:@"Robert" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dictionary setValue:@"Redford" forKey:@"lastname"];
[dictionary setValue:@"1234567" forKey:@"eds"];
[dictionary setValue:@"12.01.1965" forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];

NSError *error;

//serialize the dictionary data as json
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.106:8888/postPerson.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body
[urlRequest addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *dataRaw, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:dataRaw
                          options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", json];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView * av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Got error %@.\n", error] message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [av show];
    }

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:result message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av show]; // --> this is to check the array sent with POST-method which is json_encode() in the php script above.
```

I hope this may be useful...

Answer (score 2):

Since we're dealing with strings, the variables in your VALUES require them to be quoted:

```
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$eds', '$dateOfBirth')
```

For more information on string literals, visit:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this did not make the trick. I also had the same problem when passing in strings directly (like VALUES ('string1', 'string2', etc). And it seems to work when running the script in the browser but not from my app... I thought it was an obj-C error but I receive the json_encode() response in my app so the script is also executed. I'm going mad...

Comment: In fact it looks like the $body (form POST method) from php://input is correct since it produces an array I can json_encode() and get back to my app (I see the result in a UIAlertView), but this sounds like the sql statement is not called since it is not working. But again, it is not called only from my app because I can add an entry in mySQL database from the browser with default strings (VALUES ('string1'...). I can't figure out what is going wrong...

Comment: @Trichophyton You're welcome. If you could post more code and relative to what you just said, it would help me or others who are keeping track of your question, to hopefully give you the right solution.

Comment: @Trichophyton Or, is that your full code? I'm not too familiar with `php://input` and TBH, I never worked with it before. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I added my obj-C code in my question. THe php script is the full code... It is working from the browser but not form the obj-C code, although this one can return the json... According to php.net, php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body (I quoted them :-)).

Comment: @Trichophyton I'd really like to help you further, but I unfortunately do not know anything about obj-C code. I'll ask a friend of mine to visit your question and will see if he can help you further with it. Update: He's not there today. But I'll keep at him and see.

Comment: @Trichophyton You're welcome. *Crossing our fingers*. Cheers - Btw, If you could post your HTML form too, and check the form's action and method. Lordie, it could be anything.

Comment: I have no html code. It is not sent from a web HTML form but directly from my iOS application. I try to send data (the dictionary in the obj-C code) by calling the php script inside the obj-C method. There is no visible web interface.

Comment: @Trichophyton Ok thanks. Well, I got a hold of a friend of mine to see if he could see what could be wrong, but told me that it wasn't the kind of code he's used to working with. Sorry about that.